# need to run <input> through a function when I click a button (using bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, function

Basically, I'm using bootstrap as my CSS, but I'm running into a problem. When I click the button (`id="myQuestionButton"`), I want it to take the input from the input box (`id="myInput"`) and run it through `function checkQuestionWords()`.

Here's the block of code pertaining to the input and button:

```
<div class="input-append span9 offset3">
  <form>
    <input class="span4" type="text" id="myInput" 
    placeholder="Enter your question."></input>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" id="myQuestionButton">
    Let's check second.</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here's where it will print the preliminary results (for now just in a `<div> </div>`):

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

And here's my function so far:

```
function checkQuestionWords(){
  var theInput = document.getByElementId("myInput");
  var theQuestion = theInput.trim();
  var questionWords = ["who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how"];
  var isItGood = false;

for (var i=0, i<7; i++){
  var holder1 = questionWords[i];
  var holder2 = holder1.length;
    if (theQuestion.substr(0,holder2) == questionWords[i]){
      isItGood = true;
      break;}
    else{
      isItGood = false;}}

if (isItGood == false){
  document.getByElementId("results") = "Please enter a question...";}
  //the above just reminds them to begin with a question word; see questionWords
else{
  document.getByElementId("results") = "all is good";}
```

}

I tried doing a whole `onclick=checkQuestionWords()"` inside of the `<button ...></button>` but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Pls show the exception

Comment: one little thing. no closing tag for input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems in the above code:

Problems are:

1. `getByElementId` should be `getElementById`
2. `document.getByElementId("myInput")` should be `document.getElementById("myInput").value;`
3. `document.getByElementId("results")` should be `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML`

See the working code below:

```
<script>
function checkQuestionWords() {
    var theInput = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var theQuestion = theInput;//.trim();
    var questionWords = ["who", "what", "where", "when", "why", "how"];
    var isItGood = false;


    for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
      var holder1 = questionWords[i];
      var holder2 = holder1.length;
        if (theQuestion.substr(0,holder2) == questionWords[i]){
          isItGood = true;
          break;}
        else{
          isItGood = false;}}

    if (isItGood == false){
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Please enter a question...";
    }
      //the above just reminds them to begin with a question word; see questionWords
    else{
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "all is good";
    }

    return false;

}
</script>
<div class="input-append span9 offset3">

    <input class="span4" type="text" id="myInput" 
    placeholder="Enter your question."></input>
    <button class="btn" type="submit" id="myQuestionButton" onclick="checkQuestionWords();">
Let's check second.</button>

</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Okay. This seems to work when I just put it on a blank page (with the appropriate links to the CSS/html header/body/etc.), but not when I have it with the rest of my code. I literally tried copying/pasting it in (and removing the old code), but to no avail.

Comment: Can you edit your question with new changes. So that I can review and check it.

Comment: Nvm, I got it to work. The problem seemed to be that the question would be upper case ("How") while the array was full of lowercase question words ("how"). I just did   theQuestion = theQuestion.toLowerCase(); and everything worked out.

Comment: The reason it worked on another page was because I had been typing the question all in lowercase; I was getting frustrated so I was just typing as fast as I could, thereby neglecting the use of shift.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem just that you are using 
`var theInput = document.getByElementId("myInput");` ?

This will give you the input control with the `id` of **myInput** but not the text inside it.  You want something more like

```
var theInput = document.getByElementId("myInput").value;
```

This will give you the actual text which you can then assign to `theQuestion` using

```
var theQuestion = theInput.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple calling like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById["myQuestionButton"];
btn.onClick = checkQuestionWords;
```

Comment: `getElementById` is a function, not an object.